# Streaming video from nodejs to an open player

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, video-player

Odd ball question for somebody just getting started with html5 players and streaming video....

When using YouTube long videos can be scrolled towards then end then played from there.  Assuming YouTube first pulls down metadata like total video start/stop points and a bunch of thumbnails for scrolling.

Is this possible with an open html5 video player (like projekkter)?  Reason asking is that I have video data inside a mongo database that I would like to stream similar to the YouTube player.

Inside mongo I have a bunch of smaller h264 files each in a document: actual raw h264 usually 1000kb (max 2 seconds), creation timestamp (long), and potentially a converted format (like mp4) for known clients.  Idea is to query off a time range and order by creation time then piping the results into readable stream.  There is a nice ffmpeg module to take streams and reformat if needed.  Thought about piping the stream to the client with binaryjs and appending it into the player.

But the source directives in the documentation are usually URLs plus I need to lock down the start/stop point for the total video being played plus thumbnails.

Comment: Is MediaSource API the only hook into the video element?  Is it usable outside Chrome in the near future?  Or are there other ways to do what I want?

Comment: Or is an image player more appropriate like http://livepx.com/animated-jpg-web-player LivePx or jsmovie?